# problema con libreria scrollify

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando que me funcione el scroll vertical con esta libreria y por mucho que intento seguir su pagina oficial o cualquier tutorial no me funciona.

https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify

Dejo mi código:

```js
   $(function() {
       $.scrollify({
        section : "section"
       });
      });
```

```html
<script 
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/scrollify/1.0.19/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>

    <section class="section uno" ><div>uno</div></section>
    <section class="section dos" ><div>dos </div></section>
 <section class="section tres" ><div>tres</div></section>
 <section class="section cuatro" ><div>cuatro</div></section>
 <section class="section cinco" ><div>cinco</div></section>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro estás siguiendo las instrucciones? En esta línea falta un punto `section : "section",  ` Puedes comparar con la línea `section : ".example-classname",` del ejemplo de [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/#overview)

Comment: Acabo de editar tu código. He cambiado la referencia al script de scrollify y funciona perfectamente (también he quitado la coma que te sobraba pero eso no estaba dando problemas). ¿Cuál es el error que te da?

Comment: @Kiko_L seía la referencia del script por que ahora si que me funciona, Gracias por la ayuda, podría haber estado horas y horas tocando de todo menos esto X(